# Finding the largest price increase/decrease in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a way to get the largest price difference (in a time frame, e.g. 24 hours) in a MySQL table using a source and productId as reference.

Here is a sample product, `productId` 22.

```
id  price  createdAt           updatedAt           sourceId productId
21  799.00 2017-07-26 19:46:46 2017-07-26 19:46:45 1        22
853 920.00 2017-07-26 06:46:46 2017-07-26 06:46:46 1        22
855 799.00 2017-07-22 16:17:11 2017-07-22 16:17:11 2        22
851 770.00 2017-07-21 16:17:11 2017-07-21 16:17:11 1        22
856 799.00 2017-07-20 16:17:11 2017-07-20 16:17:11 2        22
852 599.00 2017-07-19 16:17:11 2017-07-19 16:17:11 1        22
857 810.00 2017-07-18 16:17:11 2017-07-18 16:17:11 2        22
858 799.00 2017-07-17 16:17:11 2017-07-17 16:17:11 2        22
```

In the example above for `productId` 22 I am sorting by `createdAt`, so in this scenario I'd take id `21` and substract it from id `853`, this would give `-121`, meaning the product went down 121 dollars.

In the full data it's a mush up of `prices`, `sourceIds` and `productIds`. The goal here is to make a result look like this:

```
id  createdAt            sourceId productId adjustment
21  2017-07-26 19:46:46  1        22        -121
22  2017-07-26 16:46:46  2        22        201
23  2017-07-26 15:46:46  6        24        -20
```

Above is kind of how I am trying to get the data to look, so I'll know of the price difference of each product of each source. Then I can control the data, such as ordering by adjustment and seeing which source + product had the largest decrease or increase in a time frame.

I've tried doing a ton of sub-queries, I've probably put in a hundred examples that I've modified from Google. I can piece together parts of this, such as only getting products that have recieved a change of any kind from the past 24 hours. I've tried to merge the last two rows of each product Id, then do a math, and list all the products. It's been 2 days of trying to build this query, is it just best for me to not use queries for everything and do it on my backend?

I've even went to a support site like hackhands and they couldn't figure it out. I've exhausted all of my ideas.

Comment: Just to clarify: the largest price difference in a time frame woudl be maximum price - minimum price any time during the time frame. What you want is maximum variation from strat time in a given time frame for instance 24 hs. Correct?

Comment: Your question is to not very clear to me, I am not claiming its not clear for other as well, First problem you said you will take id 21 and subtract from id 853, confusing part why you want to do that as you said you only want to track for 24 hours time period it's not 24 hours time period(in short explanation needed), second you did not explain, will you do the same thing, means for with id 21 and 853 and so on.., and you also did not explain, what is id what is productid, and what is source id One more thing if you can clear it, clear this as well. ............

Comment: .......as i can see your first table, it seems like it's just one product i am getting it from productid is 22 in the whole table, and throught id, you are just tracking deviation in price, and source id represent some thing like like source means lets say you have three shop, like shop one shop two three, i can be completly off what i understood, and it is also possible you don't understand what i am trying to say as enlgish in not my first language, if i am off in understanding let me know, and if you don't understand what i am trying to say, blame english language not me.

Comment: "is it just best for me to not use queries for everything and do it on my backend?" Probably - yes.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion. Yeah @user2860957 my example was a bit confusing, the example of productId `22` was just showing how I'd want the function to work per unique `productId` and `sourceId`. This seems overly complex for MySQL, so as @Paul Spiegel also suggested I think I am just going to do a backend loop.

Comment: Your result set doesn't correspond to your data set. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query breaks down the problem:

1) Getting the records corresponding to start_at time of the window for each product in order to get the baseline price.

2) Gets the the records for the max price for each product in the time frame.

3) Gets the records for the min price for each product in the time frame.

4) Combines 1 and 2 and 3 to form a single record per product and shows the info and the difference between base line price and the highest and lowest in the time frame.

If you only need the bigger of the two you can add and extra layer of select wrapping this query and user GREATER(a,b) to keep one diff or the other.

```
select BOWPRICE.product_id, BOWPRICE.created_at, BOWPRICE.price, 
MAXPRICE.max_price_upd_time,  MAXPRICE.max_price, ABS((BOWPRICE.price - MAXPRICE.max_price)) max_price_diff,
MINPRICE.min_price_upd_time,  MINPRICE.min_price, ABS((BOWPRICE.price - MINPRICE.min_price)) min_price_diff
 from  
(
    select mainA.product_id, mainA.created_at, mainA.price from SOTEST mainA 
    where id in ( 
      select id
      from SOTEST N 
      where created_at = (
          select min(N1.created_at) 
          from SOTEST N1
          where N1.created_at >= '2017-07-26 00:00:00'
          and N1.product_id = N.product_id 
      ) 
      group by mainT.product_id 
    )
) BOWPRICE,
(
  select mainB.product_id, mainB.updated_at max_price_upd_time, mainB.price max_price from SOTEST mainB
  where id in(
    select id from SOTEST M
    where M.price = (
      select max(M1.price) 
      from SOTEST M1
      where M1.created_at >= '2017-07-26 00:00:00'
      and M1.created_at < '2017-07-27 00:00:00'
      and M1.product_id = M.product_id 
      group by product_id LIMIT 1
    ) 
  )
) MAXPRICE,
(
  select mainC.product_id, mainC.updated_at min_price_upd_time, mainC.price min_price from SOTEST mainC
  where id in(
    select id from SOTEST Q
    where Q.price = (
      select min(Q1.price) 
      from SOTEST Q1
      where Q1.created_at >= '2017-07-26 00:00:00'
      and Q1.created_at < '2017-07-27 00:00:00'
      and Q1.product_id = Q.product_id 
      group by product_id LIMIT 1
    ) 
  )
) MINPRICE
where BOWPRICE.product_id = MAXPRICE.product_id
and BOWPRICE.product_id = MINPRICE.product_id
```

Comment: i also thinking of writing some thing like this, but than i stay away as i was 1000% i will mess it up, and second if op ask me to change any thing i will declare war on my self, why i get involve, this should work, i am deleting my answer as well,

Comment: Holy crap, after some minor tweaks that actually works. That's absurd query time didn't increase by that much either. `Query took 0.0183 seconds`. I have a lot to learn